# tinymce and Jquery UI dialog working nicely

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, tinymce

I'm having some problems with Jquery UI Dialog and TinyMCE.
Passing data to a text area works well with UI Dialog and Jquery.
So setting data in text area like this works fine:

```
        $("#MessageDialog #messageDto_Body").val(messagedata.Body);
        $("#MessageDialog").dialog("open");
```

When I attach a tinyMCE editor to the text area it correctly adds the editor (and without the UI window the content of the text area is preserved):

```
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, 'messageDto.Body');
```

With UI Dialog the area is empty.

From what I have seen the tinyMCE works hiding the real text-area and adding a new one.
I have also tried setting the content directly but no luck:

```
  tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(messagedata.Body, {format : 'bbcode'});
```

Any advice?

UPDATE: substituted Jquery UI Dialog with jqModal and everything works. I think the problem could rely not in TinyMce but in the Jquery UI Dialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the jQuery [TinyMCE plugin](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/examples/example_23.php) will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

tinyMCE hides the textarea and adds multiple elements using the textarea's ID appended with '_' + element type. To access the contents of the iframe try something like this.

```
$("#content_ifr").contents().find("body").html(messagedata.Body);
```

Where #content is the ID of your textarea.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by initializing the editr with the TinyMCE jQuery plugin with `$('#myTextBox').tinymce(...`, after opening the dialog. CLosing and reopening the dialog doesn't seem to cause a problem with jQ UI 1.8.16.