# Making tinymce automatically open and get populated when I click on a link?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tinymce

I have a grid containing many records. Each record has some basic information such as an ID and status. What I would like to do is:

1. When a user clicks an edit HTML icon on a row I would like to
   make an ajax call to get data from my database. (I pretty much know
   how to do this already)
2. I would like to then have tinymce open in
   full screen and be populated with the data.
3. When the user clicks save on tinymce then I would like to call a function to save my data
   and have the tinymce close up.

Has anyone done anything like this? Some pointers would be very much appreciated.

Comment: This question might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/752313/tinymce-and-jquery-ui-dialog-working-nicely